Lock macOS Recovery mode for admins
I have an M1 MacBook Pro with an Admin user and a normal user, they share an Apple ID.
I want macOS' Recovery Mode to be accessible only with an Admin password, it used to be the case but changed somehow. I don't want FileVault or a Firmware Password, the normal user to be able to boot and use the computer, just not to abuse Recovery Mode.
